# Angular + Material Autocomplete: How to bind certain values only to model in md-option

Tags: javascript, angularjs, autocomplete, typescript, angular-material

I'm using Angular and Angular Material in a current project. I am using the Autocomplete feature (https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/autocomplete)  for a certain component, however, have struggled to only bind certain properties to the model that are returned for a value.

My question is **how do I bind only a single or certain values to the model in the case below**?

In this example, I have a countries.json file that I'm populating my md-select with, and several key/value pairs:

```
{"name":"Australia","tld":".au","cca2":"AU","ccn3":36,"cca3":"AUS","currency":"AUD","calling-code":"61","alt-spellings":"AU","relevance":1.5,"region":"Oceania","subregion":"Australia,New Zealand"}
```

**HTML:**
    My HTML is simply using a Autocomplete component, but I've tried to use ng-value to only bind the "cca2" value to the model, without any luck.

```
<ol-lookup-input 
items="vm.allCountries" 
ng-value="vm.allCountries.cca2" 
selected-items="vm.filter.value" 
search-field="name" 
placeholder="Type to add a country">
</ol-lookup-input>
```

**CURRENT UI:**

For obvious reasons, I don't want to send back all the country details to the backend, and there can be multiple values, which would make the payload very messy.

[image]

**IDEAL UI:**

What I really want is to just send through an array of the "cca2" values associated with each country, as below:

[image]

Comment: You seem to have a custom directive for you `md-select/md-autocomplete`. Ideally we would need to know what it does to help. Maybe you can provide a simple codepen, it supports typescript as well.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide code of the **ol-lookup-input** directive, I can't show a code that completely suits your case. However, I can still think of two solutions for the problem.

**Solution 1**

Create two seperate arrays in your controller: one for the chips component (I guess that array with **cca2** codes is not enough for this, because you want to display a country name on the chips) and second one for backend (only with cca2 codes). You can attach a function, which will be fired when user selects a country, either with using `md-selected-item-change` attribute in `md-autocomplete` or `md-transform-chip` in chips component and use it to populate the second model.

**Solution 2**

I guess there is a function in your code that sends selected countries to the backend. You can take cca2 codes out from your selected countries model just before sending them to the server.